# Run RoboElectric multiple times with different sdk version

Tags: android, robolectric

I have created a RoboElectric test class which i would like to run multiple times,

each time changing the @Config(sdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.{code}) sdk parameter,

Any ideas on how to make this happen without creating new test classes ?

Comment: What are you trying to test?

Comment: Great! Make an answer!

Answer (score 4):

Found the solution, MultiApiRobolectricTestRunner will run the test class on multiple API level configurations,

The code should look like this:

```
@RunWith(MultiApiRobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(sdk = {20, 21, 22})
public class IntegrationTest {}
```

Comment: this was deprecated and removed in [Robolectric 3.3](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/releases/tag/robolectric-3.3)

Comment: Now you can provide a config with RoboelectricTestRunner itself
`@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)

@Config(application = RoboelectricTestRisorApplication::class, sdk = [Build.VERSION_CODES.P, Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP])`